# Why this python code is not executing completely?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6

When I run the following code in pycharm it executes till ans = input("Do you want to play this game") and when I type answer yes, it should ideally execute the below code but it executes print('Thank you so much for playing, you got', score, 'questions correct')

```
print ("Welcome to the page?")

ans = input("Do you want to play this game? Yes/No")
score = 0

if ans.lower()=='yes':
   ans=input("When was Bangalore made capital city of Karnataka?")
   if ans.lower()=="1956":
      score=+1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

   ans=input("Who is the current Mayor of Bangalore?")
   if ans.lower()=="M Goutham Kumar":
      score=+1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

   ans=input("What is the GDP of Bangalore?")
   if ans.lower()=="$210 Billion":
      score=+1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

   ans = input("Who is called as father of Bangalore?")
   if ans.lower() == "Kempegowda":
      score = +1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

print('Thank you so much for playing, you got', score, 'questions correct')
```

Comment: This works for me! Could you check variable `ans`?

Comment: This is working, I tries by giving `Yes` and `yes` as input.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your code is working.
But, maybe you are inputting some whitespace after or before the word.
Or, maybe on Linux, there are inputting `ans\r`.

```py
print ("Welcome to the page?")

ans = input("Do you want to play this game? Yes/No ")
score = 0

if ans.lower().strip()=='yes':
   ans=input("When was Bangalore made capital city of Karnataka? ")
   if int(ans)==1956:
      score=+1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

   ans=input("Who is the current Mayor of Bangalore? ")
   if ans.lower().strip()=="m goutham kumar":
      score=+1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

   ans=input("What is the GDP of Bangalore? ")
   if ans.lower().strip()=="$210 billion":
      score=+1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

   ans = input("Who is called as father of Bangalore? ")
   if ans.lower().strip() == "Kempegowda":
      score = +1
      print("Correct + 1")
   else:
      print("In-correct")

print('Thank you so much for playing, you got', score, 'questions correct')
```

Comment: Yeah, whitespace was the mistake. Thank you :) but now for 2nd, 3rd and 4th question I am getting answer as incorrect even though I type exact words

Comment: You should try `ans.lower()=="m goutham kumar"` instead of capital letter in the words.

Comment: Maybe this answer can focus on the relevant line of code instead of repeating everything

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("Welcome to the page?")

ans = input("Do you want to play this game? Yes/No")


score = 0

if ans.lower()=='yes':

   ans=input("When was Bangalore made capital city of Karnataka?")

   if ans.lower()=="1956":

      score=+1

      print("Correct + 1")

   else:

      print("In-correct")

   ans=input("Who is the current Mayor of Bangalore?")

   if ans.lower()=="M Goutham Kumar":

      score=+1

      print("Correct + 1")

   else:

      print("In-correct")

   ans=input("What is the GDP of Bangalore?")

   if ans.lower()=="$210 Billion":

      score=+1

      print("Correct + 1")

   else:

      print("In-correct")

   ans = input("Who is called as father of Bangalore?")

   if ans.lower() == "Kempegowda":

      score = +1

      print("Correct + 1")

   else:

      print("In-correct")

print('Thank you so much for playing, you got', score, 
'questions correct')
```